Wireless mouse lagging on Ubuntu 24.04
I experience my wireless mouse lagging intermittently. When it happens it does not resolve until I reboot the OS.
I don't see any error in the system logs. Can someone help me debug the issue?
Output of sudo dmesg | grep -i mouse
[64496.244058] usb 1-3.1: Product: Wired Gaming Mouse
[64496.251198] input: SINOWEALTH Wired Gaming Mouse as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-3/1-3.1/1-3.1:1.0/0003:258A:0036.000B/input/input39
[64496.251534] hid-generic 0003:258A:0036.000B: input,hidraw1: USB HID v1.11 Mouse [SINOWEALTH Wired Gaming Mouse] on usb-0000:00:14.0-3.1/input0
[64496.254304] input: SINOWEALTH Wired Gaming Mouse Keyboard as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-3/1-3.1/1-3.1:1.1/0003:258A:0036.000C/input/input40
[64496.306335] hid-generic 0003:258A:0036.000C: input,hiddev0,hidraw2: USB HID v1.11 Keyboard [SINOWEALTH Wired Gaming Mouse] on usb-0000:00:14.0-3.1/input1
[64497.133221] glorious 0003:258A:0036.000B: input,hidraw1: USB HID v1.11 Mouse [Glorious Model O] on usb-0000:00:14.0-3.1/input0
[86020.812672] usb 1-3.1: Product: Wired Gaming Mouse
[86020.819932] glorious 0003:258A:0036.000F: input,hidraw1: USB HID v1.11 Mouse [Glorious Model O] on usb-0000:00:14.0-3.1/input0
[147741.758430] input: USB HID GMMK Pro Mouse as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-4/1-4.1/1-4.1:1.1/0003:320F:5046.0014/input/input58
[147741.813359] hid-generic 0003:320F:5046.0014: input,hiddev0,hidraw2: USB HID v1.11 Mouse [USB HID GMMK Pro] on usb-0000:00:14.0-4.1/input1
[147742.858595] hid-generic 0003:258A:2022.0016: input,hidraw7: USB HID v1.11 Mouse [Glorious Model O Wireless] on usb-0000:00:14.0-4.4/input0
[159225.249329] input: USB HID GMMK Pro Mouse as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-4/1-4.1/1-4.1:1.1/0003:320F:5046.001A/input/input74
[159225.304471] hid-generic 0003:320F:5046.001A: input,hiddev0,hidraw2: USB HID v1.11 Mouse [USB HID GMMK Pro] on usb-0000:00:14.0-4.1/input1
[159226.350465] hid-generic 0003:258A:2022.001C: input,hidraw7: USB HID v1.11 Mouse [Glorious Model O Wireless] on usb-0000:00:14.0-4.4/input0
[168107.313034] input: USB HID GMMK Pro Mouse as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-4/1-4.1/1-4.1:1.1/0003:320F:5046.0020/input/input89
[168107.366061] hid-generic 0003:320F:5046.0020: input,hiddev0,hidraw2: USB HID v1.11 Mouse [USB HID GMMK Pro] on usb-0000:00:14.0-4.1/input1
[182015.409367] usb 1-4.5: Product: Model O 2 Wired Mouse
[182015.418493] input: GLORIOUS Model O 2 Wired Mouse as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-4/1-4.5/1-4.5:1.0/0003:320F:823A.0022/input/input94
[182015.418697] hid-generic 0003:320F:823A.0022: input,hidraw1: USB HID v1.10 Mouse [GLORIOUS Model O 2 Wired Mouse] on usb-0000:00:14.0-4.5/input0
[182015.419996] input: GLORIOUS Model O 2 Wired Mouse Keyboard as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-4/1-4.5/1-4.5:1.1/0003:320F:823A.0023/input/input96
[182015.472625] hid-generic 0003:320F:823A.0023: input,hiddev0,hidraw2: USB HID v1.10 Keyboard [GLORIOUS Model O 2 Wired Mouse] on usb-0000:00:14.0-4.5/input1
[182015.473399] hid-generic 0003:320F:823A.0024: hiddev1,hidraw3: USB HID v1.10 Device [GLORIOUS Model O 2 Wired Mouse] on usb-0000:00:14.0-4.5/input2
[182015.811483] input: SONIX USB DEVICE Mouse as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-4/1-4.6/1-4.6:1.1/0003:320F:5064.0026/input/input101
[233388.209958] input: USB HID GMMK Pro Mouse as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-4/1-4.1/1-4.1:1.1/0003:320F:5046.0028/input/input109
[233388.264611] hid-generic 0003:320F:5046.0028: input,hiddev0,hidraw2: USB HID v1.11 Mouse [USB HID GMMK Pro] on usb-0000:00:14.0-4.1/input1
[233389.315132] hid-generic 0003:258A:2022.002A: input,hidraw7: USB HID v1.11 Mouse [Glorious Model O Wireless] on usb-0000:00:14.0-4.4/input0

Output of xinput list
Interestingly, my mouse is showing up as both a keyboard and pointer. The mouse i use is glorious model o wireless
⎡ Virtual core pointer                      id=2    [master pointer  (3)]
⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ Razer Razer Blade                         id=12   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ Razer Razer Blade                         id=13   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ ELAN0406:00 04F3:3297 Mouse               id=22   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ ELAN0406:00 04F3:3297 Touchpad            id=23   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ USB HID GMMK Pro Mouse                    id=14   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ USB HID GMMK Pro Consumer Control         id=17   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ Glorious Model O Wireless Consumer Control    id=21   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ Glorious Model O Wireless                 id=28   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎣ Virtual core keyboard                     id=3    [master keyboard (2)]
    ↳ Virtual core XTEST keyboard               id=5    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Video Bus                                 id=7    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Video Bus                                 id=8    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Intel HID events                          id=24   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Razer Razer Blade                         id=25   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Razer Razer Blade                         id=11   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Razer Razer Blade                         id=26   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=9    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Sleep Button                              id=10   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=6    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ USB HID GMMK Pro                          id=15   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Glorious Model O Wireless System Control  id=16   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ USB HID GMMK Pro Consumer Control         id=18   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ USB HID GMMK Pro Keyboard                 id=19   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Glorious Model O Wireless Keyboard        id=20   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Glorious Model O Wireless Consumer Control    id=27   [slave  keyboard (3)]


On Performance Mode
On Xorg
echo N | sudo tee /sys/module/drm_kms_helper/parameters/poll (Does not work)

Output of sudo lshw -short
H/W path           Device           Class          Description
==============================================================
                                    system         Blade 16 - RZ09-0483 (RZ09-0483SWH3)
/0                                  bus            SO690
/0/0                                memory         64KiB BIOS
/0/24                               memory         64GiB System Memory
/0/24/0                             memory         32GiB SODIMM Synchronous 5600 MHz (0.2 ns)
/0/24/1                             memory         32GiB SODIMM Synchronous 5600 MHz (0.2 ns)
/0/32                               memory         384KiB L1 cache
/0/33                               memory         256KiB L1 cache
/0/34                               memory         16MiB L2 cache
/0/35                               memory         36MiB L3 cache
/0/36                               memory         512KiB L1 cache
/0/37                               memory         1MiB L1 cache
/0/38                               memory         16MiB L2 cache
/0/39                               memory         36MiB L3 cache
/0/3a                               processor      13th Gen Intel(R) Core(TM) i9-13950HX
/0/100                              bridge         Intel Corporation
/0/100/1                            bridge         Intel Corporation
/0/100/1/0         /dev/fb0         display        AD106M [GeForce RTX 4070 Max-Q / Mobile]
/0/100/1/0.1       card0            multimedia     NVIDIA Corporation
/0/100/1/0.1/0     input11          input          HDA NVidia HDMI/DP,pcm=3
/0/100/1/0.1/1     input12          input          HDA NVidia HDMI/DP,pcm=7
/0/100/1/0.1/2     input13          input          HDA NVidia HDMI/DP,pcm=8
/0/100/1/0.1/3     input14          input          HDA NVidia HDMI/DP,pcm=9
/0/100/2           /dev/fb0         display        Raptor Lake-S UHD Graphics
/0/100/4                            generic        Raptor Lake Dynamic Platform and Thermal Frame
/0/100/8                            generic        GNA Scoring Accelerator module
/0/100/a                            generic        Raptor Lake Crashlog and Telemetry
/0/100/14                           bus            Raptor Lake USB 3.2 Gen 2x2 (20 Gb/s) XHCI Hos
/0/100/14/0        usb1             bus            xHCI Host Controller
/0/100/14/0/4                       bus            USB2.1 Hub
/0/100/14/0/4/1    input107         input          USB HID GMMK Pro Keyboard
/0/100/14/0/4/4    input113         input          Glorious Model O Wireless
/0/100/14/0/8                       multimedia     Integrated RGB Camera
/0/100/14/0/a                       input          Razer Blade
/0/100/14/0/e                       communication  AX211 Bluetooth
/0/100/14/1        usb2             bus            xHCI Host Controller
/0/100/14/1/4                       bus            USB3.2 Hub
/0/100/14/1/4/3                     communication  DockCaseAxUSBToLAN
/0/100/14.2                         memory         RAM memory
/0/100/14.3        wlo1             network        Raptor Lake-S PCH CNVi WiFi
/0/100/15                           bus            Raptor Lake Serial IO I2C Host Controller #0
/0/100/16                           communication  Raptor Lake CSME HECI #1
/0/100/1a                           bridge         Raptor Lake PCI Express Root Port #25
/0/100/1a/0                         bridge         Intel Corporation
/0/100/1a/0/0                       bridge         Intel Corporation
/0/100/1a/0/0/0                     bus            Intel Corporation
/0/100/1a/0/1                       bridge         Intel Corporation
/0/100/1a/0/2                       bridge         Intel Corporation
/0/100/1a/0/2/0                     bus            Intel Corporation
/0/100/1a/0/2/0/0  usb3             bus            xHCI Host Controller
/0/100/1a/0/2/0/1  usb4             bus            xHCI Host Controller
/0/100/1a/0/3                       bridge         Intel Corporation
/0/100/1b                           bridge         Raptor Lake PCI Express Root Port #21
/0/100/1b/0        /dev/nvme0       storage        NVMe CA6-8D1024
/0/100/1b/0/0      hwmon4           disk           NVMe disk
/0/100/1b/0/2      /dev/ng0n1       disk           NVMe disk
/0/100/1b/0/1      /dev/nvme0n1     disk           1024GB NVMe disk
/0/100/1b/0/1/1    /dev/nvme0n1p1   volume         19GiB Windows NTFS volume
/0/100/1b/0/1/2    /dev/nvme0n1p2   volume         99MiB Windows FAT volume
/0/100/1b/0/1/3    /dev/nvme0n1p3   volume         15MiB reserved partition
/0/100/1b/0/1/4    /dev/nvme0n1p4   volume         932GiB Windows NTFS volume
/0/100/1b/0/1/5    /dev/nvme0n1p5   volume         999MiB Windows NTFS volume
/0/100/1c                           bridge         Raptor Lake PCI Express Root Port #1
/0/100/1c/0        mmc0             bus            RTS525A PCI Express Card Reader
/0/100/1d                           bridge         Intel Corporation
/0/100/1d/0        /dev/nvme1       storage        Samsung SSD 990 PRO 2TB
/0/100/1d/0/0      hwmon3           disk           NVMe disk
/0/100/1d/0/2      /dev/ng1n1       disk           NVMe disk
/0/100/1d/0/1      /dev/nvme1n1     disk           2TB NVMe disk
/0/100/1d/0/1/1                     volume         1074MiB Windows FAT volume
/0/100/1d/0/1/2    /dev/nvme1n1p2   volume         1861GiB EXT4 volume
/0/100/1f                           bridge         Intel Corporation
/0/100/1f/0                         system         PnP device PNP0c02
/0/100/1f/1                         system         PnP device PNP0c02
/0/100/1f/2                         system         PnP device PNP0c02
/0/100/1f/3                         system         PnP device PNP0c02
/0/100/1f/4                         system         PnP device PNP0c02
/0/100/1f.3        card1            multimedia     Raptor Lake High Definition Audio Controller
/0/100/1f.4                         bus            Raptor Lake-S PCH SMBus Controller
/0/100/1f.5                         bus            Raptor Lake SPI (flash) Controller
/1                                  power
/2                 input0           input          Lid Switch
/3                 input1           input          Sleep Button
/4                 input10          input          Intel HID events
/5                 input2           input          Power Button
/6                 input21          input          Razer Razer Blade
/7                 input22          input          Razer Razer Blade
/8                 input23          input          Razer Razer Blade
/9                 input3           input          Power Button
/a                 input30          input          Video Bus
/b                 input31          input          Video Bus
/c                 input32          input          sof-hda-dsp Mic
/d                 input33          input          sof-hda-dsp Headphone
/e                 input34          input          sof-hda-dsp HDMI/DP,pcm=3
/f                 input35          input          sof-hda-dsp HDMI/DP,pcm=4
/10                input36          input          sof-hda-dsp HDMI/DP,pcm=5
/11                input7           input          ELAN0406:00 04F3:3297 Mouse
/12                input9           input          ELAN0406:00 04F3:3297 Touchpad
/13                enxa8e43b1750d9  network        Ethernet interface

This same mouse had no issues on Ubuntu 22.04
